# CheckSelfPermission() not running with API 24

Tags: android, permissions

Neither 
Permission Denied nor Permission Granted are showing up in my log.

However the Log.v("SPAM","1"); is working.

Does the class have to be the "MainActivity" running in order for the code to work ?

This is the class where the permissions are being used.

Another problem was that requestPermissions was not running, and the code below wasn't either. Any ideas what this could be?

```
package com.project.backgroundprocesstest;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * Created by Alex on 14/09/2016.
 */
public class LocationControl extends AppCompatActivity{
    final int REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 5;
    private Context context;
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    public LocationControl(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        this.locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v("SPAM", "1");
            this.locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new MyLocationListener(context));
        }
    }
    public LocationManager getLocationManager(){
        return locationManager;
    }
    public String getLocation(){
        Log.v("SPAM", "1");
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            Log.v("CheckPermission","Permission Denied");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
            Log.v("CheckPermission","It Does run");
        }
        else{
            Log.v("CheckPermission","Permission Granted");
            Location location = this.locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            double longitudinal = location.getLongitude();
            double latitudinal = location.getLatitude();
            String cityName = findCity(location);
            Date date = new Date();
            return setJSON(longitudinal,latitudinal,cityName,date);
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,int[] grantResults){
        switch(requestCode){
            case REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                } else {
                    Log.d("CheckPermission","User Denisd Permission");
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    public String setJSON(double lng, double lat, String place, Date date) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("longitudinal", lng);
            jsonObject.put("latitudinal", lat);
            jsonObject.put("name", place);
            jsonObject.put("created", date);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", "JSON ERROR");
        }
        if(jsonObject != null)
            return jsonObject.toString();
        else
            return null;
    }
    private String findCity(Location loc){
        String cityName = null;
        Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
        // IF any addresses which belong to the Longitudinal and Latitudinal are found,
        // set cityName and print it
        List<Address> addresses;
        try{
            addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(),loc.getLongitude(),1 );
            if(addresses.size()>0){
                System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
                cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
            }
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return cityName;
    }
    private String locationToString(Location location){
        return Location.convert(location.getLatitude(),Location.FORMAT_DEGREES)+" " + Location.convert(location.getLongitude(),Location.FORMAT_DEGREES);
    }
}
```

EDIT: No errors are popping up in log or debug.

Comment: Which is you targetSDK?

Comment: TargetSDKVersion is 24

Comment: Log.v("SPAM", "1"); is used twice (first time in the Constructor). So maybe change one of them. At present, it just seems `getLocation()` isn't called at all.

Comment: Sorry for confusing with logs, but actually the getLocation() is the only method being called

Comment: Well, this seems quite impossible: if no other log is written, this means no branch of the if-else is executed. Did you maybe set the Logcat filter so it doesn't show log entries with tag "CheckPermission"?

Comment: Problem seemed to be I was running this not within a valid activity class.

Comment: Oh, so the LocationControl activity was not  launched ("active") when this happened? (I think you may indeed have some problem with your architecture in this case) But anyway: if the method starts being executed, how can it skip the if-else ? And if it doesn't start, why is there that Log entry(SPAM)?

Answer (score 0):

You can call `checkCallingPermission (permission)` of `Context` instead